# How do I create a patch of all changes, say 10 days old, in branch B and working directory A?

Tags: git, git-patch

I tried using the command

```
git diff branch1 branch2 -- folder/ > mypatch.patch
```

But when I use

```
git am --signoff mypatch.patch
```

I get an error

```
Patch format detection failed.
```

Comment: `git am` wants to read the kind of output provided by `git format-patch`, not just `git diff`. The output from `git diff` is suitable for `git apply` but not for `git am`.

Answer (score 0):

Changes in current branch:

```
git log -p --since=10.days > mypatch.patch
```

Changes in current branch, but not in `branch2`:

```
git log HEAD --not branch2 -p --since=10.days > mypatch.patch
```

Changes in `branch1`, but not in `branch2`:

```
git log branch1 --not branch2 -p --since=10.days > mypatch.patch
```

You could also use `--before` in a similar fashion to specify upper date range:

```
git log -p --since=10.days --before=2.days > mypatch.patch
```

[Documentation for git-log](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log), sections "Commit Limiting" and "Common Diff Options".